# Rails sample app header syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am getting a syntax error for line 10; could anyone please help? To my best knowledge I have followed the learner tutorial I am using to the letter.. Thank you!

```
  app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb

    5                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>

    6                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>

    7                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>

    8             </a>

    9              

   10             <% link_to "Home," root_path, class: "brand" %>

   11 

   12                 <div class="nav-collapse">

   13                     <ul class="nav">

   14                         <li>

   15                             <%= link_to 'Home',  root_path %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comma in the wrong place.

```
<% link_to "Home", root_path, class: "brand" %>
```